# jQuery and es6 imports - how to get a global instance

Tags: jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using webpack to bundle my files but am having an issue with jQuery.  Due to legacy code, we defined a whole bunch of functions on the jQuery object on page initialization.  The problem we're seeing is if you do a

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

Each file is getting it's own instance of jQuery.  In our webpack.config, we have tried to use the ProvidePlugin to setup a global jquery namespace like so:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
 })
```

Unfortunately, that isn't truly "global".  Meaning any modifications we make to that instance in one file isn't persisted to the other files.  For example:

```
<-- file one -->
window.a$ = $;
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {};

<-- file two -->
window.b$ = $;

<-- console -->
window.a$ === window.b$  // is false
window.b$.myPlugin // is undefined here
window.a$.myPlugin // is properly set here.
```

Clearly I have a poor understanding of es6 imports.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"Clearly I have a poor understanding of es6 imports"* ES6 only provides the module *syntax* and how modules should be evaluated (namely once). Everything else, module resolution, module loading, depends on the execution environment or bundler (i.e. webpack in this case).

Comment: Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can replicate the issue, the example isn't sufficient. It isn't easy to replicate Webpack build issues, a repo would probably help. The assumptions on `import` and `ProvidePlugin` are wrong, in both cases this should result in single jQuery instance. This may happen if `jquery` belongs to different Webpack bundle chunks.

Comment: @estus What do you mean, jquery belongs to different Webpack bundle chunks?  Can you elaborate in that?  In the meantime, I'll work on creating something reproducible.

Comment: [Chunks](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#chunk-content) are parts (files) that belong to a bundle. For a single chunk the instance should be the same. Depending on the setup, several chunks may be created, possibly against developer's will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @estus, I discovered the piece that I was missing.  As he pointed out in his comment above, I was unintentionally creating new instances of jQuery when setting up a split point.

I needed to use the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) to setup a vendor file like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
       vendor: ['jquery']
    },

      ...

     plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         $: "jquery",
         jQuery: "jquery",
         "window.jQuery": "jquery",
         "window.$": "jquery"
       }),
       new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",

        // filename: "vendor.js"
        // (Give the chunk a different name)

        minChunks: Infinity,
        // (with more entries, this ensures that no other module
        //  goes into the vendor chunk)
       })
   ]
   ...
```

In conjunction with the provider plugin it was fairly straightforward to setup the global jQuery instance.